# Simulating opening of large amount of links

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I know it sounds like some attempt of black hat SEO, and maybe the source of this question had something close to that in mind, but the reason why I'm asking this is because this question really made me wonder if it is possible.

In case it is, how exactly one can simulate opening of large amount of unique links without opening the same amount of new pages?

The task is this - let's say we have a database with 5,000 links in it and by clicking a button, I want to simulate opening each link so if the site has a webcounter it will get incremented (the opening of the page will be detected) but at the same time nothing will appear on the user's page and it will stay as it is, without opening 5,000 new pages or realoading the same page again and again.

I'm sorry if this question is outside the programmer ethis. I'm asking it out of curiosity, and will be glad to read opinions if is this really possible and how could be achieved.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Call `wget` in a loop?  http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the client or from the PHP server?  do you care if the server returns a result, even if it's not displayed?  How quickly do you want the 5000 links to visited?

Comment: I don't care about speed and implementation. What is requaired is a simple page with `<a href..>` or some other element and when this element is clicked to start the process of opening the links under the conditions described above. It could be PHP, JavaScrip, jQuery or whatever implementation. Just curious if it's possible and how cna be done.

Comment: I'm not sure the answers using wget and fsocketopen will work. It seems that you want to make sure that the `webcounter` which I assume is `google analytics` will execute and that won't happen with those tools because javascript wont' be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with simple JavaScript:

```
var myLinks = ['http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example.org'];

// run this in the on click handler of the <a> tag
var imgs = [];
for (var i = 0, link; link = myLinks[i]; ++i) {
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].onload = imgs[i].onerror = function() {
        // do stuff when loading is done
    }
    imgs[i] = link; // start loading
}
```

**How it works**
Loading images is like any other HTTP request, but it's more optimized because image loading in browsers gets parallelized (up to a certain degree). The images will all fail to load, because they won't be served any images, but that's okay because you don't care.

**Caveats**

The HTTP headers sent to the server will send an `Accept` header to load an image, so it's not exactly like a page load; however, most servers don't care about it.

The browser console might show many messages that report images failed to load (obviously, because HTML ain't images).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://nashruddin.com/fetching-a-web-page-from-php-code.html) I found a nice script for opening URLs from PHP. It uses fsockopen(). The code is:

```
  <?php   

  function fetch_page($url)   
  {   
      /* get hostname and path */   
      $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);   
      $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);   


      if (empty($path)) {   
          $path = "/";  
      }         

      /* Build HTTP 1.0 request header. Defined in RFC 1945 */  
      $headers = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n"  
               . "User-Agent: myHttpTool/1.0\r\n\r\n";  


      /* open socket connection to remote host on port 80 */  
      $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errmsg, 30); 


      if (!$fp) {

          /* ...some error handling... */  
          return false;  
      }         

      /* send request headers */  
      fwrite($fp, $headers);         

      /* read response */  
      while(!feof($fp)) {  
          $resp .= fgets($fp, 4096);  
      }

      fclose($fp);


      /* separate header and body */  
      $neck = strpos($resp, "\r\n\r\n");  
      $head = substr($resp, 0, $neck);  
      $body = substr($resp, $neck+4);         

      /* omit parsing response headers */         

      /* return page contents */

      return($body);  
  }

  ?>
```

Just call fetch_page() in a loop to simulate 5,000 hits.

Comment: Thanks, nice 1, gonna w8 a little longer to see if there won't be another solutions.